# WPF how can i get row and cell data in Gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I want to get back to the amount inside the cell name,price when I click on the button in the last column, which I use in the class I wrote. (I used entityframework)
[image: [Photo Attached]]

my xaml

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                  Name="dgv1"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
                                  CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                                  CanUserSortColumns="False"
                                  IsReadOnly="True"
                                  FontSize="15"
                                  MaxHeight="330"
                                  FontFamily="B yekan" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" GridLinesVisibility="None" RowHeight="60" HeadersVisibility="Column" Background="White" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Black" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Black" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionChanged="dgv1_SelectionChanged">

                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding namebuffet}" Width="150"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="family" Binding="{Binding namefamilymember}" Width="150" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="memberid" Binding="{Binding idmember}" Width="150" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="price"  Binding="{Binding Price}" Width="150"  />
                                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="add to wallet" Width="150">
                                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Name="btnAddToWallet" Style="{StaticResource walletstyle}" Click="btnAddToWallet_Click">
                                                            <Button.Content>
                                                                <Image Source="img/wallet.png"/>
                                                            </Button.Content>
                                                        </Button>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

my c# code behind

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     dgv1.ItemsSource = B.Getbuffetinformation();
}
```

Comment: All the stuff in a row will have a datacontext of what it's templated from. Looks like that's a buffet. But in btnAddToWallet_Click you can cast sender to Button. Then cast it's datacontext to an instance of buffet ( or whatever each item is ) and you have the properties namebuffet etc in that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will click the button then you will automatically select the row, you can use this code below inside you button click event:

```
 DataRowView row= dgv1.SelectedItem As DataRowView
 String name =row["name"].ToString();
 String price =row["price"].ToString();
```

Comment: tnx for answer i try that but when i clicked on button that return null value
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'